# Disable pan on mousewheel when zooming, but retain it when dragging

Tags: d3.js

I'm trying to use a zoom feature in d3. It's the simple one, with the following code

```
var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
                    .scaleExtent([0.5, 4])
                    .on("zoom", function() {
                        this.svg.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
                    }.bind(this));
```

It's working more or less fine, so it zoom on mousewheel and pans on drag. I want that. But when zooming with mousewheel, it also pans. That, I don't want.
It should only zoom, when mousewheel and pan when dragged. Tried few things already, including separate drag functions and disabling part of the mousewheel (which I failed miserably), but to no avail.

Could You please help me?

Comment: By default, it will zoom on mousewheel to the mouse position. If you want to zoom to the center of the screen, take a look at this: https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/6226534.

Comment: Could You please make it an answer, so I can accept it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, your code will zoom centered to the mouse position.

If you want to zoom to the center of the screen, you might have to explicitly set `center()` on your zoom behavior like so:

```
var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
  .scaleExtent([0.5, 4])
  .center([width / 2, height / 2])
  .on("zoom", function() {
    this.svg.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
  }.bind(this));
```

If at any stage you need to reset the default zoom center behaviour (to zoom to the current mouse position), you can do so with:

```
zoom.center(null);
```

Src: [Zoom Center](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/6226534)